# how to sort array by date and count in ionic 2

Tags: arrays, sorting, ionic-framework, ionic2

I want to sort my array by date and count, i'm able to sort array only by date my data is as below

```
   count    date
    "0"     "2018-03-06T07:09:02+00:00"
    "0"     "2018-03-06T07:07:02+00:00"
    "0"     "2018-03-06T07:06:03+00:00"
    "0"     "2018-03-06T07:02:06+00:00"
    "0"     "2018-03-06T06:39:55+00:00"
    "0"     "2018-03-06T06:30:14+00:00"
    "1"     "2018-03-06T06:22:20+00:00"
    "1"     "2018-03-06T06:07:04+00:00"
    "0"     "2018-03-06T06:03:17+00:00"
    "14"    "2018-03-01T10:28:27.998000+00:00"
    "0"     null
    "0"     null
    "0"     null
```

my code is below..

```
this.nodelist.sort((a, b) => {//lastDate dsc

      if (new Date(b.lastDate) > new Date(a.lastDate)) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (new Date(b.lastDate) < new Date(a.lastDate)) {
        return -1;
      }

      return 0;
    });
```

i want to sort array by count and date both means if array is having count > 0 then it should be first then count with zero and on last all other records. can anyone help me to solve this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46520444/ionic-3-loop-list-and-divide-into-2-columns

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use your code and modify it like this:

```
this.nodelist.sort((a, b) => {
    // 1st property, sort by count
    if (a.count > b.count)
        return -1;

    if (a.count < b.count)
        return 1;

    // 2nd property, sort by date
    if (new Date(b.lastDate) > new Date(a.lastDate))
        return 1;

    if (new Date(b.lastDate) < new Date(a.lastDate))
        return -1;

    return 0;
});
```

**How does it work?**
The first two if statements will sort the array by count.
If count is equal, the code will consider the second property (lastDate).

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
let xyz = numbers.sort(function(a, b) {
  var countA = a.count;
  var countB = b.count;
  var dateA = new Date(a.date);
  var dateB = new Date(b.date);

  if(countA == countB)
  {
      return (dateB < dateA) ? -1 : (dateB > dateA) ? 1 : 0;
  }
  else
  {
      return (countB < countA) ? -1 : 1;
  }

});

console.log(xyz);
```